# What is "Open in AppSheet" option?

Tags: google-sheets, appsheet

Today I noticed new option in *Tools* menu of Google Sheets: "Open in AppSheet".

For one spreadsheet it's inactive:

[image]

For other spreadsheet it is active:

[image]

What is the purpose of this new option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a new feature that Google is rolling out.
AppSheet analyzes the data structure of your sheet and -if it can- creates a prototype app.
As advertised, it is

> The intelligent no‑code platform
> Create apps to transform your
> workplace.

Please find more info on the official site [Appsheet.com](https://blog.appsheet.com/) or at the blog [blog.appsheet.com](https://blog.appsheet.com/)